# Simple script to list members of a group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm totally new to Powershell and AD, so your explanations might need to be a bit explicit.

I can list all users in my domain. Now I'm trying to list only users that belong to the group `Power Users`. I think my filter is wrong, as I don't get anything. I have read that it's also not a good idea to filter by `memberOf`, is that correct?

```
...
$DEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$DSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]$LDAPPPath)
$DSearcher.SearchRoot = $DEntry 
$DSearcher.filter = "(&(objectCategory=person) (memberOf=CN=Power Users))"
$R = $DSearcher.FindAll()

# Print R ...
```

There might be a sintaxis error, but this didn't work either:

```
$DSearcher.filter = "memberOf=CN=Users"
```

I also tried the full name as:

```
$DSearcher.filter = "memberOf=CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
```

---

Format source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

Comment: do you have a group named "power users"? that is usually a LOCAL group, not an AD group. for the local group, you can use `Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Power Users'`

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't using the AD powershell module?

Comment: Yes, `Power Users` and `Users` exist. I tried with `Users` because it has no space, just in case was a syntax error. AD PS module is not installed/available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [adsisearcher] Type Accelerator works well for this

```
#LDAP Query
$search = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(memberOf=CN=Power Users,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com))"
$search.FindAll()
```

Alternatively and easier to remember, you could

```
$samAccountName = "Power Users"
$group = ([adsisearcher]"samAccountName=$samAccountName").FindAll()
$group.Properties.member
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=Contoso,dc=Com"
$Members = $Group.Member | ForEach-Object {[ADSI]"LDAP://$_"}
```

Comment: For some reason it is taking very long to finish and I am not getting results...